# WP E-commerce wpml translation or multilingual

Tags: multi-language, e-commerce, support

Ok, i need to setup a shop, my choice, WP, now, the shop should be french and english, with product variation and newsletter tracking, this is the baseline

Now, everybody is talking about wp e-commerce from instinct, a company that look serious, but now, there is a paid, a free, a commercial version. There is getshopped.org wich is ? the same or another site, there is wpml that said we will be compatible, but waiting for the new version. On the site, they dont talk about wpml, of state compatibility. No mean to contact without registering..

So here is my question. How can we get strait answer from a company that have a HUGE base of client that use there product.

Is it possible to make a multilingual shop with e-commerce and wpml or qtranslate ? and where i can get answer...

It's sad to see that even before installing the software, it so difficult to get help... just imagine when i will be on deadline...

Tell me from your experience please, and thanks in advance

Comment: Here is my shortlist of the REAL, INSTALLED program i try and test with the same data, to get a real feel : Catabol-TomatoCart-ShopperPress-Prestashop-ZenCart-Shopp-DigiShop-OpenCart-WPML-Dukapress-LemondStand-Shopify. OUF!, now, no winner !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is extremely frustrating to find a plugin that works without errors and is still customisable.

I have tried the following:

**Shopp** - www.shopplugin.net 
(very good, but will only support WPML in the next update - unknown release date)

**Marketpress** - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-ecommerce/ 
(workes well, but is pretty limited, not sure if the paid version is that much better)

**WP e-Commerce** - getshopped.org
(works, but the structure of it is very heavy and caused some errors within my system, not sure if that is the standard. You will need to pay for the Gold Cart Plugin. The free setup is not very usable)

**The Cart Press** thecartpress.com
(last time I tried they were still in a very early stage. I will actually try it again now and hope it has improved)

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer is that multilingual e-commerce is very difficult and poorly supported across the board.

Even stand alone e-commerce applications that have many years of history have no support or very poor support for multilingual content, enterprise level platforms included.

I would expect that since WordPress itself does not really have strong support for multi-languages that the e-commerce plugins should be avoided for this type of site.

ps. I live in the same city as you so I have experience in this market.

Comment: ok, now that said... what is the best of the worst ?

Comment: I would look at x-cart, prestashop and opencart, but the last time I did this was a year or so ago and the e-commerce landscape changes very fast, I would avoid wordpress and Megento. Also considering doing 1 site in for each language a major problem is SEO, it's more work but less problems, I actually recommend doing this unless you have enterprise level needs.